# Tailwind Column Layout Problems

Tags: css, next.js, flexbox, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm building my portfolio as a React app (NextJS) and styling it with Tailwind.

In my projects section, I have each project as a card which has an expandable details section.

Currently, I am using the columns feature of Tailwind to have 3-2-1 column depending on viewport. This is leading to some weirdness when things are being resized:

The parent is this:

```
<div className="container lg:columns-2 2xl:columns-3 gap-10 justify-self-center self-center">
</div>
```

And then the code maps through my data file to fill it with entry components, which don't have any styling that would impact the column layout (other than `break-inside-avoid-column`).

Right now, when I expand my first entry's description, it pulls the third column's entry into the second column. It also is pretty broken outside of Chrome generally, and I'm not sure why.

I've tried remaking it using a grid layout, which fixed the issue of things moving between columns when I don't want them to, but it also made it such that each entry grew in height to match the new height of an entry with expanded details, which is not what I want to happen.

I've tried remaking it using flexbox and a basis of 4/12, but this has the same aforementioned issue as the grid layout.

Basically, I want 3 locked-in columns, and I want each entry to have a fixed height until it is expanded. I don't want any entry other than the one being expanded to grow in height. I also do not want any entries to move between columns unnecessarily.

An added want is that it would work well on Safari, but this is somewhat ancillary to my main goals.